# Las sesiones de PHP no persisten una vez cerrado el navegador

Tags: php

Utilizo PHP en xampp con el clásico:

```
session_start();
```

La sesión persiste si se cierra la pestaña pero no persiste si se cierra el navegador.

¿Será alguna modificación de la versión de PHP? Utilizo la última disponible.

En resumen: la sesión se mantiene cuando se cierran la pestañas o se recarga la pagina, pero se destruye al cerrar el navegador, y necesito que se mantenga igualmente hasta que el usuario cierre sesión explícitamente.

Edito: Sucede lo mismo con un servidor Node.js ¿quizás el problema es un cortafuegos?

Comment: Usar cookies no es recomendable, puede traer problemas, mejor guarda la sesion en una base de datos y cambias su valor con una funcion

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Espero que mi respuesta sea de ayuda. Si tienes alguna duda déjame un comentario en la respuesta. Si necesitas la solución para Node.js te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta para ello, ya que el código es diferente.

Comment: @BrunoLevet ¿en qué te basas para decir que el uso de cookies no es recomendable? ¿A qué problemas te refieres?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debes cambiar [`session.cookie-lifetime`](https://php.net/es/session.configuration#ini.session.cookie-lifetime) en el archivo `php.ini` para indicar una duración de la cookie mayor a `0` (el valor por defecto `0` significa "hasta que el navegador se cierre"):

> **session.cookie_lifetime** *(integer)*
>
> `session.cookie_lifetime` especifica el tiempo de vida en segundos de la cookie que es enviada al navegador. El valor `0` significa "hasta que el navegador se cierre". Por defecto es `0`. Véase también `session_get_cookie_params()` y `session_set_cookie_params()`.

---

También puedes hacer uso de [`session_set_cookie_params()`](https://php.net/es/session-set-cookie-params) para el mismo propósito:

```
<?php
/* Establecemos una duración de un día */
session_set_cookie_params(24 * 60 * 60);
session_start();
```

Comment: funciono con: > session_set_cookie_params(24 * 60 * 60); Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Usa setcookie para guardar la sesión, en set cookie hay un parámetro que es el tiempo que dura la cookie, cuando inicie sesión guarda la cookie por unos seg o min para probar, cierra el navegador y vuelves a abrirlor para ver, no recuerdo ahora muy bien la sintaxis pero para ver los datos guardo en la cookie es $_COOKIE["nombre_de_la_cookie)"]